# how to show the number of children next to the QTreeView folder?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside2

I am building a file management system based on **QFileSystemModel**, and need to display the number of subfolders next to the folder.
[image]

First, I need to get the number of children.

I know **rowCount()** will not work. because it is only calculated when the folder is expanded.

Second, I need to put the number after the folder name.

I know that I should add a custom column to **QFileSystemModel**, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to obtain the number of rows it must be done after calling the fetchMore method. All of the above must be implemented in the delegate.

```py
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QDir
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QFileSystemModel,
    QStyledItemDelegate,
    QTreeView,
)


class StyledItemDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super().initStyleOption(option, index)
        if index.column() != 0:
            return
        model = index.model()
        if model.hasChildren(index):
            if model.canFetchMore(index):
                model.fetchMore(index)
            option.text += " ({})".format(model.rowCount(index))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication.instance()
    if app is None:
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    view = QTreeView()
    view.resize(640, 480)
    view.show()

    model = QFileSystemModel()
    model.setRootPath(QDir.currentPath())

    view.setModel(model)
    view.setRootIndex(model.index(QDir.currentPath()))

    delegate = StyledItemDelegate(view)
    view.setItemDelegate(delegate)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I'd add that if the text should only indicate subfolders, as the OP initially requests, `QDir(index.data(QFileSystemModel.FilePathRole), '', filters=QDir.AllDirs|QDir.NoDotAndDotDot).count()` could be used instead of `rowCount()` (possibly with some caching, but that could be a bit tricky as QFileSystemModel has some issues with the fs change notifications).